# Generate PHP class from bash script

Tags: php, bash

I am new to Shell script. I am writing a shell script to generate a php class. I have successfully generated a class from that script but the problem is that I am unable to declare php variables in that class.
For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make root class
echo "Adding Root class..."
cat > Example.php << EOF
<?php 
require_once (dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../CmlmAPICore.php';

class $1 extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public $coreAPI;
    public $globalPath;
    public $path;
    protected function setUp() {
        $this->coreAPI = new CmlmAPICore();
        $this->globalPath = $GLOBALS['DATA_FOLDER'];
}
}
```

These variables are not being shown in the class generated. Everything else is showing fine. 
Generated class is:

```
<?php 
require_once (dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../CmlmAPICore.php';
class Audios extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

   public ;
    public ;
    public ;

    protected function setUp() {
        ->coreAPI = new CmlmAPICore();
        ->globalPath = ['DATA_FOLDER'];
}
}
```

=> $1 is the parameter I pass as class name when i run shell script.

I guess it is not identifying "$" sign in this. 
Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Why don't you generate the class using PHP, maybe with a little help from a template engine? BTW: `dirname(__FILE__)` is the same as `__DIR__`.

Comment: Yes. I've also implemented that way using skeletons in php. Point is I need to append test cases in this class afterwards by reading some files.
Which does not seem possible with that.

Comment: What you mean with "does not seem possible"? You can use `file_put_contents()` to append to an existing file, for example.

Comment: I've created this shell script because i need a number of classes of same pattern, just class name and the path differs.
Then, I will iterate over a directory and will make functions for each of the files in that directory and those functions will be appended in this class.
Those functions will have same functionality, just a parameter differs on the base of which I  will change the name of the function.

Comment: You are right. It can be implemented with the help of php. Like, I've just seen runkit_function_add. I am just looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add '\' before '$'

```
public \$coreAPI;
public \$globalPath;
public \$path;
protected function setUp() {
    \$this->coreAPI = new CmlmAPICore();
    \$this->globalPath = \$GLOBALS['DATA_FOLDER'];
```